# Column-wise repeating same function and having additional column for each column

Tags: r

I am trying to find monthly max value from daily stock data for each company. My data is like this in Excel:

```
Date      MSFT         AAPL         GOOGL
25-01-05  21.02984824  4.873362261  88.56
26-01-05  21.02176605  4.886889984  94.62
27-01-05  21.10258791  4.913269044  94.04
```

I can manage to get monthly max by this code for each company

```
attach(Historical_Stock_Prices_R)
rdate <- as.Date(Date1, "%d-%m-%y")
rCompanies <- c("rdate", "MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOGL")
Df<-data.frame(sdate = rdate, sMSFT = MSFT, SAAPL = AAPL, sGOOGLE = GOOGL)
monthlymaxMSFT <- tapply(MSFT, format(rdate, '%y-%m'), max)
monthlymaxGOOGL <- tapply(GOOGL, format(rdate, '%y-%m'), max)
```

Now I want to get all companies monthly max together and create a new monthly max column automatically for each company. Can you help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `aggregate`...

```
Historical_Stock_Prices_R$Date <- as.Date(Historical_Stock_Prices_R$Date, format="%d-%m-%y")

mMax <- aggregate(Historical_Stock_Prices_R[,-1],
                  by=list(Month=format(Historical_Stock_Prices_R$Date,"%y-%m")),
                  FUN=max)
```

By the way, the use of `attach` is discouraged.  It is normally better to keep data frames intact to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew Gustar